# What if one forgot to separate the challa?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, separating-challah

What if one completely forgot to separate the Challa? Is it still possible to do it after baking? If not, that means the bread is not eligible to be used for Shabbat? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea 327, 5:

> אם לא הפריש החלה בצק אלא אפה הכל הרי זה מפריש מן הפת.‏
>
> If he did not separate the challa from the dough, but already baked the whole, he has to separate it from the bread.

Note, it's not allowed to separate the challa on Shabbat (see OC 339, 4).

Comment: Note in the Diaspora you can eat on Shabbat and separate Challah after Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why is the rule different in Diaspora? Because there challah is derabanan?

Comment: @DanF Yup. (more precisely it's a double derabanan, since all challah nowadays is derabanan anyway as most Jews don't live in Israel)

Comment: @Double AA see demai 4, 4, for this I wrote the additional fact that challa is not eaten bizman haze bechuts laarets

Comment: @kouty I don't see what oyu refer to in the mishna there, but a kohein can eat Challat Chu"l even bizman hazeh if he goes to the mikva.

Comment: @Double AA if there was kriat shem challa without hafrasha, a kohen can come on shabbat and eat it and metaken. but because kohanim cannot eat challa even behuts laarets, thi is not possible.

Comment: @Double AA kriat shem in Demai 4, 4. The Ber Heytev I quoted says that a kohen nowadays cannot eat challa because challat EI itself is never eaten

Comment: @kouty that's fine for the ber heytev if that was his custom, but that custom isn't the only one in the world. since when did an ashkenazi concern for lineage of kohanim after the crusades extend to an ashkenazi giving to a temani kohein? or a temani giving to a temani kohein? even in ashkenaz people continued to give to kohanim on pesach. some achronim didn't think it was a binding custom at all to not give it to kohanim (eg. arukh hashluchan, gra).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57432/discussion-between-kouty-and-double-aa).

Comment: Most Jews live in Israel